# Did historical protestants identify themselves as "catholics"?

Tags: catholicism, church-history, protestantism

Did Historical protestant churches like Lutheran, Calvinist, Anglican, etc... and their founders identify themselves as lowercase "catholic"(Universal in sense) in their founding years? or the Catholic - catholic difference came from [branch theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_theory) later?

*Inspired from: [Regarding "Roman Catholics" and names for other groups](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/78/58919), [What is the correct terminology when referring to (Roman) Catholicism?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4248/58919)*

Comment: All Protestants of all ages would have considered themselves part of the catholic/universal church! Why wouldn't they?

Comment: @curiousdannii I am asking did they considered themselves catholics in their founding years, in their writings.

Comment: It's part of the Niceno-Constantinopolitan Creed, which the Reformers enthusiastically endorsed.

Comment: @curiousdannii How do we know NCC used "catholic" in a universal sense or like in the [Augustinian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catholic_(term)#Augustine_of_Hippo) way with the combination of Bishop of Rome

Comment: The meaning of the word 'catholic/Catholic' has changed from its usage in ancient times to its usage pre-reformation and then its usage post-reformation. [See Oxford English Dictionary](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/28967?redirectedFrom=catholic#eid) 1 a _Of or belonging to the ancient Christian Church ***before the Great Schism*** between Eastern and Western Churches in the 11th cen_

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question needs to be edited in regard to historical context. Martin Lutehr regarded himself as 'catholic' but that word mow has a different meaning.

Comment: @NigelJ How does it needs to be edited?

Comment: @WenuraRavindu I suggest you have a look at the Oxford English Dictionary in regard to what the word means in English. Then re-word your question as to what, exactly, you are looking for.